# Unable to resolve additional project configuration using Resteasy in Intellij

Tags: java, google-app-engine, intellij-idea, gradle, resteasy

Hai I am new to Resteasy, I working on resteasy with gradle for app engine application, I am using Intellij IDE, here I am using the latest version in the dependencies,

```
compile group: 'org.jboss.resteasy', name: 'resteasy-jaxrs', version: '3.0.23.Final'
compile group: 'org.jboss.resteasy', name: 'resteasy-jackson2-provider', version: '3.0.23.Final'
```

I am getting below errors, but I using the older version,

```
compile group: 'org.jboss.resteasy', name: 'resteasy-jaxrs', version: '3.0.10.Final'
compile group: 'org.jboss.resteasy', name: 'resteasy-jackson2-provider', version: '3.0.10.Final'
```

The application working fine, but I need to use new version how can I resolve it? can any one solve this? my folder structure and build.gradle is given below

when I am mentioning new version in the dependencies, There is popup(shown in the image)

[image]

I am getting warning as

```
Warning:<i><b>root project 'Sample': Unable to resolve additional project configuration.</b>
Details: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ArtifactResolveException: Could not download commons-codec.jar (commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Could not read entry '22da77b0d76ea8df17298218f3ec1f87:commons-codec.jar (commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9)' from cache artifact-at-repository.bin (C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches\modules-2\metadata-2.23\artifact-at-repository.bin).
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: null
Caused by: com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Buffer underflow.</i>
```

when I tries the try the task `appengineRun`, the error I am getting is,

```
    05:56:35 PM: Executing external task 'appengineRun'...
:compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
> Could not download commons-codec.jar (commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9)
   > Could not read entry '22da77b0d76ea8df17298218f3ec1f87:commons-codec.jar (commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9)' from cache artifact-at-repository.bin (C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches\modules-2\metadata-2.23\artifact-at-repository.bin).

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 0.447 secs
Buffer underflow.
05:56:36 PM: External task execution finished 'appengineRun'.
```

[image]

in `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-gradle-plugin:+'
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}


apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.appengine'

dependencies {
    //working--//compile group: 'org.jboss.resteasy', name: 'resteasy-jaxrs', version: '3.0.10.Final'
    compile group: 'org.jboss.resteasy', name: 'resteasy-jaxrs', version: '3.1.3.Final'

    //working--//compile group: 'org.jboss.resteasy', name: 'resteasy-jackson2-provider', version: '3.0.10.Final'
    compile group: 'org.jboss.resteasy', name: 'resteasy-jackson2-provider', version: '3.1.3.Final'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine:+'
}

appengine {
    run {
        port = 8080
    }

    deploy {
        stopPreviousVersion = true
        promote = true
    }
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7
```

Comment: did you try to include compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9' into your gradle build file?

Comment: No I didn't, @MichaelMeyer

Comment: are you going to try?

Comment: No, am I need to include  'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9' ? @MichaelMeyer

Comment: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
> Could not download commons-codec.jar (commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9)

Comment: yes, this is the error I am getting, but for this am I need to include 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9' in the gradle dependencies? @MichaelMeyer

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the build behind a proxy? In that case, you don’t have direct access to maven central and you need to set your proxy settings accordingly as per this [doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#N109F2). A similar error and resolution is discussed on the gradle discussion forum [here](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/could-not-resolve-commons-codec-commons-codec-1-6/16814).